# Why does this code involving "? super T" compile successfully?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand `? super T` to see how it works, and I'm stuck at the below example:

```
class Thing {
  AnotherThing change() { return null; }
}

class AnotherThing {}

interface Fn<A, B> {
  B run(A a);
}

class Stream<T> {
  <R> Stream<R> map(Fn<? super T, ? extends R> fn) {
     return null;
  }
}

void method() {
  Stream<Thing> s = new Stream<>();
  s.map(a -> a.change());
}
```

The strangest point is that Java can infer that `a` is `Thing` and, therefore, can invoke `change()`.

But that is not true. From `Fn<? super T, ? extends R> fn`, `a` could be `Thing` or `java.lang.Object`; Both are "super" of `T` (or, in this case, `Thing`).

I am missing some lesson around `? super T`. I was wondering if anyone can explain why Java can deduce that `a` is `Thing`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a custom `Fn` interface, let's talk about `java.util.function.Consumer<T>`. If you're not aware, the `Consumer` interface has a single abstract method: `accept(T)`. When you use `Consumer<? super T>` you're saying that the *implementation* of `Consumer` can accept `T` *or* a supertype of `T`. What this doesn't mean, however, is that any supertype of `T` can be passed to the `accept` method—it must be of the type `T`. You can see this with the following:

```
Consumer<? super CharSequence> con = System.out::println;
con.accept("Some string"); // String implements CharSequence
con.accept(new Object()); // compilation error
```

However, if you have some method like:

```
void subscribe(Consumer<? super CharSequence> con) { ... }
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
Consumer<Object> con = System.out::println;
subscribe(con);
```

This allows flexibility in the API. The caller can pass a `Consumer` designed to accept `T` (i.e. `CharSequence`) or a supertype of `T` (e.g. `Object`). But the *actual* type passed to the `accept` method will still be `T` (i.e. `CharSequence`), it's just the *implementation* of the `Consumer` can be more general. The above wouldn't work if the parameter of `subscribe` was declared `Consumer<CharSequence>` instead.

A `Consumer` is, unsurprisingly, a *consumer*. When something can be *produced* it is often best to use `? extends` instead of `? super`. This is known as *Producer Extends Consumer Super* (PECS). You can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Going back to your example, you have a class named `Stream<T>` with a method `Stream<R> map(Fn<? super T, ? extends R>)` and you ask how it knows that `T` is a `Thing`. It knows this because you've declared `Stream<Thing>` which makes `T` a `Thing`. When you call the `map` method you are implementing the `Fn` inline. This makes the implementation use `Thing` for `T` and, based on the return signature inside the lambda, use `AnotherThing` for `R`. In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
Fn<Thing, AnotherThing> f = a -> a.change(); // or you can use Thing::change
Stream<Thing> stream = new Stream<>();
stream.map(f);
```

But you *could* pass a `Fn<Object, AnotherThing>` to the `map` method. Note, however, that when using:

```
Fn<Object, AnotherThing> f = a -> a.change();
Stream<Thing> stream = new Stream<>();
stream.map(f);
```

The *declared* type of `a` will now be `Object` but the *actual* type will still be `Thing` (i.e. `T`).

Comment: Very nice answer.  Thanks for taking the time.  I learned a lot from this...that part of it that my head could handle.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the last example (which is discriminating enough to help with my understanding). Now I understand it. The type was already settled as `T`. But `T` can also be `Object`. So, allowing `Fn<Object, Another>` is more generally and nicer (depending on what we want). And I can understand why Java infers `a` as `T`. It is because the type is actually `T` and it is the most inclusive (e.g. supporting the  largest number of methods). That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> But that is not true. From `Fn<? super T, ? extends R> fn`, `a` could be `Thing` or `java.lang.Object`; Both are "super" of `T` (or, in this case, `Thing`).

You shouldn't say "`a` *could* be `Thing` or some some supertype," you should say "`a` *can* be `Thing` or some supertype". In the definition of `map`, where you take the `Fn<? super T, ? extends R> fn` as a given, the argument type of `fn` is already chosen by the caller of `map`. Inside the implementation of `map` you should use the past tense, because someone else has already chosen the type for you, and you have to make sure the code in `map` works no matter what it is. But, when you are *calling* `map`, you get to *choose* what the type of `a` is, as long as it is a supertype of `Thing`. In your code, `a`'s type *can* be `Thing` or `Object`, it's your choice. Because you haven't specified which, Java is nice and chooses the most specific possible type, `Thing`, for you, so that you have the biggest possible repertoire of methods available.

In general, if you *have* a `F<? extends/super T> f`, then the type parameter has already been chosen for you, and just you have to deal with whatever it is. The type bound is then your "friend"; it gives you additional information about what the parameter could be. In the opposite situation, if you *need* a `F<? extends/super T> f`, then you can choose the type parameter to be whatever it needs to be to fit your needs. The type bound is then your "enemy"; it limits the choices you can make for the parameter.